# Reduction for NP-hardness

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\text{Min}_{i\neq j\neq s\neq t} |x_i x_j-x_sx_t|\\
s.t: Ax=b\\
x\geq 0;  
\end{align}
This problem can be seen as an instance of non convex optimization problems. How can the NP-hardness be shown using a suitable reduction?

Comment: This problem, as written, is a more specific instance of http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/7931/276.